# TypeScript Generic uses default type instead of given type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm writing the implementation of an `insert post` use case. I'm studying the Clean Architecture and I want to create an blog API, where you can create, read, update and delete posts.

The Clean Architecture principles says you have to isolate your application into layers, where each layer is responsible to abstract your code as much as possible. I divided my code into three main layers: `core` (the most "immutable" abstractions, where I define the data models and the use cases), `app` (where I wrote the main application code, like validations and other stuff) and `resources` (the place for the less abstract code, like database connection, adapters, etc).

The general data was abstracted into the `core` layer, since it's the most fundamental information of my API. But the general data (most specifically `id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `is_deleted` fields) was abstracted into the `app` layer, because it's database dependent - the `id` field can be both a number (for general `SQL` databases) or a string (for `MongoDB`, for example). Then, i just join the two abstractions into one single model to create the "definitive" application models.

But there's a problem with this: the use cases abstractions uses the `id` data to define its implementation rules. By example, you have the `InsertPost` use case, where the return data is the `id` of the new created post. Since the `id` is only defined at the `app` layer, and Clean Architecture don't allow you to request data from more external layers, how can this abstraction know what type of `id` he's returning? The solution I found is to abstract the `id` type into the two possible types (`number` or `string`), and only provide the definitive type at the `app` layer.

This is the described `InsertPost` use case:

```
// ----- IMPORTS -----
type Id = number | string;

interface Post<IdType extends Id = Id> {
    title: string
    description: string
    body: string
    author_id: IdType
}

interface SuccessfulResponse<T> {
    results: Array<T>
}
// -------------------

export namespace InsertPost { 
    export type Params<IdParam extends Id = Id> = Post<IdParam> 
} 
 
export interface InsertPost<IdType extends Id> { 
    insert: (params: InsertPost.Params) => Promise<SuccessfulResponse<IdType>>
}
```

I wrote the `Params` type from the `InsertPost` namespace to have a Generic Type that only accepts types derived from the `Id` type. The `IdType` should also have an default type when no type is given. My problem is that TypeScript is using the default `Id` type no matter if a valid alternative type was provided or not.

This is my implementation of the `InsertPost` use case:

```
// ----- IMPORTS -----
type Id = number | string;

interface Post<IdType extends Id = Id> {
    title: string
    description: string
    body: string
    author_id: IdType
}

interface SuccessfulResponse<T> {
    results: Array<T>
}

namespace DefaultData {
    export type Id = number
    export type IsDeleted = boolean
    export type CreatedAt = Date
    export type UpdatedAt = Date
}

interface DefaultData {
    id: DefaultData.Id
    is_deleted: DefaultData.IsDeleted
    created_at: DefaultData.CreatedAt
    updated_at: DefaultData.UpdatedAt
}

interface InsertPostRepository  {
    insertPost: (user: Post) => Promise<DefaultData.Id>
}

function successfulResponseDataFormatter<T>(data: Array<T> | T): SuccessfulResponse<T> {
    return {
        results: Array.isArray(data) ? data : [data]
    };
}

namespace InsertPost {
    export type Params<IdParam extends Id = Id> = Post<IdParam>
}

interface InsertPost<IdType extends Id> {
    insert: (params: InsertPost.Params) => Promise<SuccessfulResponse<IdType>>
}
// -------------------

export class InsertPostService implements InsertPost<DefaultData.Id> {
    constructor(private readonly insertPostRepository: InsertPostRepository) {}

    async insert(params: InsertPost.Params<DefaultData.Id>): Promise<SuccessfulResponse<DefaultData.Id>> { // TypeScript throws an error at this line
        const { title, description, body, author_id } = params;

        // Validation functions here

        const id = await this.insertPostRepository.insertPost({
            title,
            description,
            body,
            author_id
        });

        return successfulResponseDataFormatter(id);
    }
}
```

[(Here's a link to this code)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgJlAvFAdgVwLYCMICcoA%20UAzsLgJYoDmA3AFB2XB4BmAhgMbQAKA9qQB54AFXDQIAD2Yo4xWAmTwAfFADedKJqjBywADYQAXCTKUqGrXAjEOFMDt4pjpCtQuasvOCGem3WqDY0YAALXlwAfXI4YxExOgBfBiZWTmgAZTQOLmJiFjQ9ACVrMEdiCAFhFXUA3GsC4GJjAEFcXDYQSqVEhhQ2DBK0qAARCHYG4bZgNjV3KElS3GBtMXkkVEwcXDmF8OXQSFhiUYNmBShPXgM2FB2JRf3VgGE6qYg4ZuXkSeY7h5XDgBVMBwN4fL4jN49RgoZi4dhcEZjIJ6YA-GY1LTRYyjcao9EAOngc3IxAiVlO7xxyImUzYROOEEpcDmtggYIiU2peLRdIJL3ZZ0%20czQII5XKRPMJwNBQuA0JS8KGMBQ5SWfFIxVKxF04RAmnUAEhKGrgBrgMYABRoNXGc0ASiQKm4uF4GFJFVxKN50yJcG6STo%20RQHAcKBIWRyeQKxWIpVVEHRADFwhgpnCupbZWwWm0Ol1CFBhPbjJlstZo0USmUKlVZoa6sA0Lhw0aG-VUU0oK12iACaSex0s3THQB%20KDZqDGADa2YAunRDQl6IG%20gM48qE%20r%20MtMZpdksATw2O0MMQhHBuCf%20vMpBAZHJ4OtlOtzRer6eA8lYalESrTW%20cSHJI0iyPI1QkluFpQJaYDXmesRQeaBIfv0xCOogzquu65QCGWUb5FWcY1heoiQEoX4APSUVAAC09EMYxTGMQwB7LBwehsLksBITu6R4AAbuQiLkBgYAGAMsKPrxgherSvovkaHBlGQWTAOEsEUAJbxQK8cCOHo%20omngZo7lq-C6rgPg8QBZkQNqlkgI6qiBoaXEgCGUDGUssHwV2-4mchqFngIcn4nyygllALpuh6eGRhWhGxvGuFhT69LKNUUDUVAABq6RPF40ChK6ADucg3PMbThIE%20whKSUB6JQECLoaymqru2i6AYAA0E7WLY5D2OQjh9Z43h9UEoThFECAJOscGnsQ9CtTluVsE1sojeGwahttcghHgLWte1pBeecbClWwujaPVxD9jJwDmTq6lWQ9tmkJabaGjo%20gQD1rWGlYNh2GGAOGhD40gODENTWEkTRK1CT2itEONs24bEAluRJdWCbJqm6Z4Ja0Qo4uSQJEAA)

TypeScript throws the following errors:

> Property 'insert' in type 'InsertPostService' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'InsertPost'.

> Type '(params: Params) => Promise<SuccessfulResponse>' is not assignable to type '(params: Params) => Promise<SuccessfulResponse>'.

> Types of parameters 'params' and 'params' are incompatible.

> Type 'Params' is not assignable to type 'Params'.

> Type 'Id' is not assignable to type 'number'.

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.

From what I've tested, this only happens when I export the type from inside a `namespace` (unfortunately, I need to use it). I really can't see where I'm going wrong; is there something I'm missing to code, or is this a TypeScript bug?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/wRJx5w) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: @jcalz Done! Please say if now it's good enough.

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/w2KVzN) meet your needs?  If so I can write up an answer; if not, please consider [edit]ing the example code to demonstrate a failing use case.

Comment: @jcalz I feel so dumb by not thinking this solution! Yes, this solves my problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in your example, an `InsertPost<XXX>` needs to have an `insert` method whose argument is of type `InsertPost.Params`, which evaluates to `Post<Id>`; note how this is independent of `XXX`. But your `InsertPostService` has an `insert` method whose argument is of type `InsertPost.Params<DefaultData.Id>`, which evaluates to `Post<DefaultData.Id>`. This is not the same type as `Post<Id>`, and so you get a compiler error.  It's possible that there are some technical issues surrounding [parameter bivariance](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance) but that's the basic problem you're having.

Presumably you want `InsertPost<XXX>` to have an `insert` method whose argument depends on `XXX`.  The most plausible candidate I can think of given your other code is that it should be of type `InsertPost.Params<XXX>`:

```
interface InsertPost<IdType extends Id> {
    insert: (params: InsertPost.Params<IdType>) => Promise<SuccessfulResponse<IdType>>
    // -----------------------------> ^^^^^^^^ <--- added this
}
```

Once I do that your code starts to compile, since your `InsertPostService` implements `InsertPost<DefaultData.Id>`.  It's always possible you could run into other issues down the line, but this is at least a reasonable first step.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgJlAvFAdgVwLYCMICcoA+UAzsLgJYoDmA3AFB2XB4BmAhgMbQAKA9qQB54AFXDQIAD2Yo4xWAmTwAfFADedAJDBywADYQAXCTKUqmuBGIcKYbbxRHSFapqy84IRyZca2aYAAWvLgA+uRwRiJidAC+DEysnNAAymgcXMTELGi6AEqWYPbEEALCKuoauJY5wMRGAIK4uGwgpUqxDChsGAVJUAAiEOw1-WzAbGqakoW4wFCgkPJIqJg4uFMSM3ML0DDEg-rMClBuvPpsKBtb82JQAMJVYxBw9XPIo8xXwdu3AKpgcCeLzeAyeHUYKGYuHYXAGQz8umAHwmFXCRkGw0RyIAdPBNORiCELIdnuj4SMxmxcfsICS4JprBAgSExmTMUjKdiHkyjq9NGgAczWXD2Tj-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-VuuQAjwcaJqm0g4uONgOrYHR5iG4h21SzzvOs3ygYC0gjTrLQ5ogeaJo0CwrBsf0EY0DGtpAdGMd2oJQnCCaYgtc6McrasA2IErMjKktIxjOMEzwI1whJydYiAA)